# git push origin [local-branch] tries to push into remote main branch instead of creating a new one

Tags: git, github, merge, branch, git-branch

I have forked a foreign repository whose "main" branch is called `develop` (instead of `master`) and made several commits on this `develop` branch.
Now I want to create a new branch of the initial foreign repository's `develop` branch (and not the `develop` branch of the one I forked and worked on) so as to work without my previous changes from scratch, like so:

- `git fetch upstream` (to get the latest copy of the foreign repo)
- `git checkout -b "my-new-branch" upstream/develop` (create a new branch from `upstream/develop`)
- `git push origin my-new-branch` (push the branch to my remote repo on github)

So I created a local branch called fix-3894 but whenever I use the "`git push origin my-new-branch`" command, I get this output:

```
! [rejected]        fix-3894 -> develop (non-fast-forward)
```

Basically, instead of transferring this local new branch on the remote repository, it tries to push it into the develop branch which is ahead of it and naturally faces a rejection. What I ultimately want is having both branches on the remote repository of mine, develop AND fix-3894.

Is my understanding of how branches work incorrect? I've been doing a lot of searching but haven't found anything to match my case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do a `git branch -avv` to see if `my-new-branch` has `origin/develop` as an upstream branch. That would be strange, and maybe related to [origin refspec](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/refs-and-the-reflog/refspecs).

If you want to force the upstream branch, do a:

```
git push -u origin my-new-branch:my-new-branch
```

Comment: Forcing the upstream branch seems to have done it, thank you.